# MakeBuild - Make Failed: mkdir: /usr/local/aws-sam-cli/1.76.0/dist/libselinux.so.1: no version information available (required by mkdir)

Tags: typescript, lambda, makefile, github-actions, cmake-gui

I'm trying to build the sam project with sam build command but getting the error no version information available in sam build stage, need some input on how to pass the version information of mkdir so the build stage would be successful I have tried various workarounds but it's not working

here is the error

Error: CustomMakeBuilder:MakeBuild - Make Failed: mkdir: /usr/local/aws-sam-cli/1.76.0/dist/libselinux.so.1: no version information available (required by mkdir)

here its make file

```
.PHONY: build-RuntimeDependenciesLayer build-lambda-common
.PHONY: build-getAllItemsFunction build-getByIdFunction build-putItemFunction

build-StoresFunction:
    $(MAKE) HANDLER=src/handlers/stores.ts build-lambda-common
build-loginFunction:
    $(MAKE) HANDLER=src/handlers/login.ts build-lambda-common
build-addStoreFunction:
    $(MAKE) HANDLER=src/handlers/add-store.ts build-lambda-common
build-updateStoreFunction:
    $(MAKE) HANDLER=src/handlers/update-store.ts build-lambda-common
build-bulkInsertStoresFunction:
    $(MAKE) HANDLER=src/handlers/bulk-insert-stores.ts build-lambda-common
build-sendEmailFunction:
    $(MAKE) HANDLER=src/handlers/send-email.ts build-lambda-common

build-lambda-common:
    npm install
    rm -rf dist
    echo "{\"extends\": \"./tsconfig.json\", \"include\": [\"${HANDLER}\"] }" > tsconfig-only-handler.json
    npm run build -- --build tsconfig-only-handler.json
    cp -r dist "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/"

build-RuntimeDependenciesLayer:
    mkdir -p "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs"
    cp package.json package-lock.json "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/"
    npm install --production --prefix "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/"
    rm "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)/nodejs/package.json" # to avoid rebuilding when changes doesn't relate to dependencies
```

here is the pipeline code of github actions

```
name: GitHub-Actions

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  AWS_REGION: ap-south-1
  LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME: Absolute
  ZIP_FILE_NAME: mycode.zip

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: Production
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install --force

      - name: install make
        run: sudo apt-get install -y make
      
      - name: install mkdir
        run: sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils

      - name: Build function
        run: sam build

      - name: check build folder
        run: cd .aws-sam/build && ls -all

      - name: Install zip
        uses: montudor/action-zip@v1  

      - name: Zip output
        run: zip -rv mycode.zip . -i build/AddStoreFunction/* build/BulkInsertStoresFunction/* build/GetAllStoresFunction/* build/LoginFunction/* build/template.yaml 
        working-directory: .aws-sam
      
      - name: List Files
        run: cd .aws-sam && ls -all
      
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Update Lambda function code
        run: aws lambda update-function-code --function-name Absolute --no-cli-pager --publish --zip-file fileb://.aws-sam/mycode.zip
```